# 404 error when using modules from controller layer with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have a projects that contains modules that represents the layers (dao, service, controllers, models). I am using @ComponentScan but steel when I access the rest api that my controllers provide I get 404 error. From what i was Reading both my main class and my controllers should be in the same package or to tell @ComponentScan() which packages to scan. I tried it all but it does not recognize the classes inside my modules - I think this is the main problem but I’m not sure. I would like to get some help and understand why this in happening. Thank you[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
@EnableMongoAuditing
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.vimalesh"})
@EnableWebFlux
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories("com.vimalesh.data.repository")
public class FundsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FundsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Mention the package name that you want to scan like above.

Thanks

Comment: I already tried to do this, but my problem is that my controller is inside a module, that the @ComponentScan does not recognize. For example my controller class is in a module called “nationalMessageController”, and my main class is not in this module. (A module contains its own Pom.xml file etc.) I added my file tree to the question.

Comment: publish your module into jar and import in the root module or attach the submodule in the root project in ide (IntelliJ)